# ¿ Cómo solucionar el boton de "consultar" de SQlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

Tengo el siguiente código :

**Para guardar información**

```
public void alta (View v)
 {

    AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this,"administracion", null, 1); //Creamos instancia llamada Admin
    SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getWritableDatabase(); //Creamos base de datos y writable para decir que es totalmende modificable

    String dni = et1.getText().toString();
    String nombre = et2.getText().toString();
    // String colegio = et3.getText().toString();
    //  String nromesa = et4.getText().toString();

    ContentValues registro = new ContentValues();  //Clase para guardar datos

    //LO QUE HAY ENTRE COMILLAS ES LO MISMO LLAMADA EN LA CLASE SQLITE DE JAVA,IMPORTANTE LOS NOMBRES.
    registro.put("dni", dni);
    registro.put("nombre", nombre);
    // registro.put("colegio", colegio);
    //   registro.put("nromesa", nromesa);

    bd.insert("votantes", null, registro); //null siempre por defecto
    bd.close(); //Cerramos si no da problemas.

    et1.setText("");
    et2.setText("");
    //et3.setText("");
    //et4.setText("");

    Toast.makeText(this, "Se cargaron los datos de la persona",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //CARTEL TOAST PARA AVISAR A USER.
}
```

**Para consultar**

```
public void consulta(View v) {
    AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this,
            "administracion", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getWritableDatabase(); //Create and/or open a database that will be used for reading and writing.

    String dni = et1.getText().toString();//Me interesa solo dni porque es lo que voy a consultar

    Cursor fila = bd.rawQuery(  //devuelve 0 o 1 fila //es una consulta
            "select nombre,colegio,nromesa  from votantes where dni=" + dni, null);
    if (fila.moveToFirst()) {  //si ha devuelto 1 fila, vamos al primero (que es el unico)
        et2.setText(fila.getString(0));
        // et3.setText(fila.getString(1));
        //  et4.setText(fila.getString(2));
    } else
        Toast.makeText(this, "No existe una persona con dicho dni" ,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    bd.close(); //Cerramos la base
}
```

El caso es que ambas cosas funcionan, pero el problema que tengo es que para que me consulte los datos guardados tengo que introducir dicho dato y lo busca y me lo muestra. Lo que yo quiero es que al clickear en "consultar" directamente me salga automáticamente solo, que no tenga que buscar nada, me muestre todo lo que existe.

Answer (score 0):

lo que entendí es que no te agrada el hecho de estar consultando o dándole al botón de consultar entonces te sugeriría que usaras TextWatcher..

Y una ayuda más quizás podrías agregarle este código a tu inquietud de..
"Lo que yo quiero es que al clickar en "consultar" directamente me salga solo, que no tenga que buscar nada, me muestre todo lo que hay."
que se encuentra en beforeTextChanged. espero te sirva : )

```
mi_editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            // Evento mientras escribes..
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            // Evento antes de escribir, acá harías un "select nombre,colegio,nromesa  from votantes OJO: siempre y cuando mi EditText esté vacío.. osea mi_editText.getText().toString().isEmpty() me retornaría true si se encuentra vacío mi_editText
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            // Evento después de escribir
        }
    });
```

Comment: Puedo abrir un chat y te comento mi caso? Tengo un dilema porque sí que busco eso pero estoy casi casi y necesito aclararlo, podrías?

Comment: Porque eso dónde lo pongo exactamente ? Lo que yo quiero es que el usuario al poner un numero en el edittext y se guarde , este SIEMPRE ahi a no ser que lo borre.

Comment: puedes crear una variable de preferencia que se seté siempre el edittext, sería una variable String

Comment: a ver, yo no soy experto en esto y menos en base de datos, me hablas de cosas que yo no se interpretar, por eso digo de chat si no , no me voy a enterar marlon :S

Comment: vale está bien pero.. no te entiendo chat ? yo recién sé que existe stackoverflow y que ayuda mucho a los desarrolladores, ahora no sé si existe un chat para esto

Comment: Por favor referirse a [Enviar mensajes a Usuarios con información sensible](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/605/227) antes de proveer información de contacto personal.